# IntelliJ Scala SBT scala.slick package not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, slick

I tried play around with Slick. The file is in IntelliJ project under

```
src/main/scala/slickfx/PlaygroundSlick.scala
```

In `build.sbt` I have:

```
name := "SlickFX"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4",
   "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" %  "3.2.0",
   "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
 )
```

My source code is:

```
package slickfx
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

object PlaygroundSlick extends App {
}
```

Now, the import `scala.slick` is red and won't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refresh the project in sbt:

`View -> Tool Windows -> SBT`

Then click on the refresh button.

Comment: Thanks you. But that had no effect.

Comment: Can you see if the dependencies got downloaded to `~/.ivy2` folder?

Answer (score 0):

It works, when the call is `import slick`, not `import scala.slick`. Apparently the package structure was changed, but the documentation was not.